# Encryption/decryption program not working properly

Tags: java, encryption, ascii

I am trying to build a program that takes the characters with ascii values from 32 to 126 and shifting them over by 9 spaces to encrypt them. Then I want to decrypt it. It successfully decrypts most of the values but the last bunch do not. Here's my code below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final int SIZE = 95; // total # of ascii vals being used
    int[] availableChars = new int[SIZE];
    int[] ePhrase = new int[SIZE];
    int[] dePhrase = new int[SIZE];

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        availableChars[i] = (i + 32);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        ePhrase[i] = encrypt(availableChars[i] - 32);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        dePhrase[i] = decrypt(ePhrase[i] - 32);
    }
    System.out.print("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    System.out.print("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        System.out.print((char)availableChars[i] + " ");
        if(i >= 10){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

    System.out.print("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        System.out.print((char)ePhrase[i] + " ");
        if(i >= 10){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }   

    System.out.print("\n");

    for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++){
        System.out.print((char)dePhrase[i] + " ");
        if(i >= 10){
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }

}

public static int encrypt(int val){
    return ((val + 9) % 94) + 32;
}

public static int decrypt(int val){
    return ((val - 9) % 94) + 32;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apart from two minor issues your algorithm is OK. The first flaw is that the modulo-operation must consider all characters of the alphabet and that is 95 instead of 94 as already explained by Willis in his answer.

The second problem is that you use a *wrong* modulo-operator. During decryption the term `(val - 9)` can become negative. However, for negative numbers the mathematical definition of the modulo-operation differs from the definition in many programming languages (including Java). In the Caesar-cipher-algorithm the mathematical modulo-operator is referred to and thus, has to be used in the implementation. See also: [Encrypting/Decrypting a string using a Affine cipher using the original 128 ASCII table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54583472/encrypting-decrypting-a-string-using-a-affine-cipher-using-the-original-128-asci/54596575#54596575)

The mathematical modulo-operator can be defined in terms of the Java modulo-operator `%` as follows:

```
private static int mod(int a, int b) {
    return ((a % b) + b) % b;
}
```

Alternatively, the method `int Math.floorMod(int a, int b)` can be used. See also: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#floorMod(int,int)

To use this `mod`-operator (and also the proper divisor `95`) replace in your `encrypt`-method

```
return ((val + 9) % 94) + 32;
```

with

```
return mod(val + 9, 95) + 32;
```

and in your `decrypt`-method

```
return ((val - 9) % 94) + 32;
```

with

```
return mod(val - 9, 95) + 32;
```

Then the output becomes:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 
  ! " # $ % & ' ( ) *  +  ,  -  .  /  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ?  @  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  \  ]  ^  _  `  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~  
) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ?  @  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  \  ]  ^  _  `  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~     !  "  #  $  %  &  '  (  
  ! " # $ % & ' ( ) *  +  ,  -  .  /  0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  :  ;  <  =  >  ?  @  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z  [  \  ]  ^  _  `  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i  j  k  l  m  n  o  p  q  r  s  t  u  v  w  x  y  z  {  |  }  ~
```

Now, plain and decrypted text match and all characters of the plain text are shifted by 9 in the encrypted text.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things going on here.

The first one is that `SIZE` is 95 but then you're modding with 94. That's going to result in two different plaintext characters mapping to the same encrypted character.

To understand the issue with `decrypt`, imagine what happens when the encoded character is, say, 37. You subtract 32 before calling `decrypt`, giving 5. (Why not do this in `decrypt`?) Then you subtract 9 giving -4. Next, mod 94 gives still -4. Then you add 32 giving 28, which is outside your allowed range.

What you should do instead of subtract 9 is add 85, which is 94 (your number that I think is wrong, but let's go with it) minus 9. Instead of -4 you now have 90. Then you mod 94 (still 90) and add 32 to get 122, which is within your allowed range.

Comment: If this was the right answer, could you give it a check mark please? (The other answer is good too, but the person just expanded on the points I made.)