# Algorithm will not encrypt/decrypt properly

Tags: java, encryption

I tested the below code with all ASCII values from 64 - 90 inclusive (All uppercase letters) and adjusted accordingly so instead of:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < c.length(); i++){
      info[i] = ((int)c.charAt(i) - 32);
  }
```

I would replace the 32 with 64 (so the ASCII value of A would save in the array as 0). Furthermore, in my encryption and decryption functions I would replace 95 with 26 (26 letters).

However, if I apply this to all values between 32-126 inclusive (95 characters) and adjust the values accordingly, the values become incorrect and I don't know why. Here is my whole main function below (note that the formula used in encryption and decryption is just an example one I used and I plan on changing the values later on):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String c = "sd344rf"; // could be any set of characters within the range
  int[] e = new int[c.length()]; // encrypted set
  int[] d = new int[c.length()]; // decrypted set

  int[] info = new int[c.length()];
  for(int i = 0 ; i < c.length(); i++){
      info[i] = ((int)c.charAt(i) - 32);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++){
      e[i] = encryption(info[i]);
  }

  for(int i = 0; i < c.length(); i++){
      d[i] = decryption(e[i]);
  }

  display(info);
  System.out.println();
  display(e);
  System.out.println();
  display(d);

}

public static int encryption(int x){
    return mod(3*x + 9,95);
}

public static int decryption(int x){
   return mod(9*x - 3,95);
}

public static void display(int[] arr){
    for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
      System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: your `encryption()` and `decryption()` operations are not truly inverse operations (meaning that except for some special cases `decryption(encryption(x)) != x`). Actually, only for 92 does it hold: `encryption(92)` gives `0`, `decryption(0)` gives `92`

Comment: The inverse of `3 * x + 9` is `(x - 9) / 3`, not `9 * x - 3`. I'm not sure where that second formula even comes from.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. However, the issue still persists. I fixed the issue in the code and replaced the return in decryption with mod((x - 9) / 3,95). What else may I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you are trying to implement an *affine* cipher. For an affine cipher the encryption is

```
y = mod(n * x + s, m)
```

and the decryption

```
x = mod(ni * (y - s), m)
```

with

```
x: Value of the character to encrypt
y: Value of the encrypted character
m: Number of characters in the underlying alphabet
n, s: Key of the encryption
```

`n` and `s` must be chosen so that they are between `0` and `m - 1`, inclusive. In addition, `n` has to be chosen so that `n` and `m` are coprime. `ni` is the modular multiplicative inverse of `n` modulo `m` and is determined by `n*ni mod m = 1`.

This is in more detail explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affine_cipher.

---

If the values `u, v` associated with the characters don't start at `0` the values have to be shifted by an offset equal to the value of the first character (provided that there are no gaps) and the formulas become

```
x = u - offset
y = v - offset 

v = mod(n * (u - offset) + s, m) + offset
u = mod(ni * ((v - offset) - s), m) + offset
```

---

Thus, you've to replace in the `main`-method

```
info[i] = ((int)c.charAt(i) - 32);
```

with

```
info[i] = (int)c.charAt(i);
```

The `encryption`-method becomes:

```
public static int encryption(int u) {
    return mod(n * (u - offset) + s, m) + offset;
}
```

and the `decryption`-method

```
public static int decryption(int v) {
    return mod(ni * ((v - offset) - s), m) + offset;
}
```

with the fields

```
private static int m = <Number of the characters in the alphabet>;
private static int n = <Key (factor)>;   // n between 0 and m-1 and moreover, n and m have te be coprime
private static int s = <Key (summand)>;  // s between 0 and m-1
private static int offset = <Value of the first character of the alphabet>;
private static int ni = <Modular multiplicative inverse of n modulo m>;
```

Moreover, for the `mod`-operation the following method is used (see [Encryption/decryption program not working properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54779199/encryption-decryption-program-not-working-properly/54782881#54782881)):

```
private static int mod(int a, int b) {
    return ((a % b) + b) % b;
}
```

---

Example 1: Uppercase letters A - Z:

```
private static int m = 'Z' - 'A' + 1;    // 26
private static int n = 3;                // Choose e.g. n = 3: n = 3 < 26 - 1 = 25 and moreover, 3 and 26 are coprime
private static int s = 9;                // Choose e.g. s = 9: s = 9 < 26 - 1 = 25
private static int offset = 'A';         // 65
private static int ni = 9;               // 3*9 mod 26 = 1
```

Test:

```
String c = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
```

Output (with characters instead of their values):

```
Plain text:     ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
Encrypted text: JMPSVYBEHKNQTWZCFILORUXADG
Decrypted text: ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

---

Example 2: All characters between 32 (Space) and 126 (~), inclusive:

```
private static int m = '~' - ' ' + 1;    // 95
private static int n = 3;                // Choose e.g. n = 3: n = 3 < 95 - 1 = 94 and moreover, 3 and 95 are coprime
private static int s = 9;                // Choose e.g. s = 9: s = 9 < 95 - 1 = 94
private static int offset = ' ';         // 32
private static int ni = 32;              // 3*32 mod 95 = 1
```

Test:

```
String c = " !\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~";
```

Output (with characters instead of their values):

```
Plain text:      !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
Encrypted text: ),/258;>ADGJMPSVY\_behknqtwz}!$'*-0369<?BEHKNQTWZ]`cfilorux{~"%(+.147:=@CFILORUX[^adgjmpsvy| #&
Decrypted text:  !"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~
```